# Image motion when scrolling using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

Can someone please suggest a tutorial/resource or give an example of basic image motion using jquery. I have been searching for a few weeks now via Google and trying various tutorials and templates and I am having difficulty finding an example of what I thought would be a simple animation.

I am trying to figure out how to create an effect so as you scroll down the page, a small image moves from point A to point B. The motion could be diagonal, horizontal, vertical, etc. I just want to specify a start position and end position and scroll start and end to reach that destination.

The idea is, I am going to take a few different wireframe CAD images and do an exploded assembly/reassembly scrolling effect. As you scroll down the CAD assembly explodes. As you scroll back up the process reverses and the assembly reassembles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not parallax. Parallax scrolling is having different layers animated at different speeds. What you are asking is how do I move objects based on the page's scroll position. Best to edit your question to get more appropriate answers

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    
    var animationData = [
    {
      id: "section1",
      startX: 100,
      startY: 50,
      deltaX: +20,
      deltaY: -5,
    },
    {
      id: "section2",
      startX: 75,
      startY: 50,
      deltaX: -20,
      deltaY: -5,
    },
    {
      id: "section3",
      startX: 50,
      startY: 75,
      deltaX: -40,
      deltaY: +15,
    },
    {
      id: "section4",
      startX: 75,
      startY: 75,
      deltaX: +30,
      deltaY: +35,
    },
    ];
    
    // scrollTop() will be in the range of 0 to scrollMax
    var scrollMax = $("#content").height() - $("#scrollarea").height();    
    var scrollArea$ = $("#scrollarea"); // cache ref for efficiency
    
    // position objects and show
    $("#section1").offset({ top: animationData[0].startY, left: animationData[0].startX});
    $("#section2").offset({ top: animationData[1].startY, left: animationData[1].startX});
    $("#section3").offset({ top: animationData[2].startY, left: animationData[2].startX});
    $("#section4").offset({ top: animationData[3].startY, left: animationData[3].startX});    
    $(".section").show();
    
    scrollArea$.scroll(function(){
      
      var scrollPerc = scrollArea$.scrollTop() / scrollMax; // 0.0 to 1.0
      
      var sec1Left = animationData[0].startX + (animationData[0].deltaX * scrollPerc);
      var sec1Top = animationData[0].startY + (animationData[0].deltaY * scrollPerc);
      var sec2Left = animationData[1].startX + (animationData[1].deltaX * scrollPerc);
      var sec2Top = animationData[1].startY + (animationData[1].deltaY * scrollPerc);
      var sec3Left = animationData[2].startX + (animationData[2].deltaX * scrollPerc);
      var sec3Top = animationData[2].startY + (animationData[2].deltaY * scrollPerc);
      var sec4Left = animationData[3].startX + (animationData[3].deltaX * scrollPerc);
      var sec4Top = animationData[3].startY + (animationData[3].deltaY * scrollPerc);
      
      $("#section1").offset({ top: sec1Top, left: sec1Left});
      $("#section2").offset({ top: sec2Top, left: sec2Left});
      $("#section3").offset({ top: sec3Top, left: sec3Left});
      $("#section4").offset({ top: sec4Top, left: sec4Left});

    });
});
```

```css
.section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: none;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#section3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section4 {
  background-color: green;
}

#content { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;

}

#scrollarea {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollarea">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="section1" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section2" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section3" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section4" class="section"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW... That's about all I can say. That has got to be one of the most word for word precise answers to a question I have ever received in all my time on StackExchange. You literally replicated the exact desired result. BRAVO! I will have to take this now and make it work in my application, but what a fantastic stating point. Thank you very much! I wish I could give you more credit! As the OP, everyone should up vote this answer!

Comment: @K Scandrett is it possible to have this example flow with the page using the pages normal scroll instead of a dedicated scroll? Also, it seems the blocks are static in position. The idea is for them to move vertically on the page as you scroll until they are ultimately out of frame. Basically the ultimate plan is to start scrolling down the site, the assembled object appears from bottom, fully explodes by the time it reaches top of page, and then disappears off screen as you continue scrolling down the site.

Comment: Yes, just change `"scrollarea"` to `window` - http://jsbin.com/ceqalerici/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Ok excellent, let me try that again. Yes sorry, I missed that link. I deleted my previous comment just as you re posted.

Comment: Yes this is looking really good. I really appreciate you helping me with this solution. The only last problem I see is, the sections dont appear to stop spreading. There doesn't appear to be an upper limit, ie, they are not stopping at their assigned deltas, they just keep expanding off screen which is expanding the sites width up until you run out of vertical scroll space.

Comment: I'm also trying to understand each part of your Jcode so I can implement a slightly more complex version where for example more than just 4 blocks explode in more than just 45 deg directions. If I am understanding this implementation thus far, it seems that may be a limitation of this example. Also looking into how to reverse it such that as you scroll down the image assembles instead of explodes. Like I said, just exploring the limitations of this example. Thank you!

Comment: The deltas are reached at the point of full scroll. You will need to play around with the maths to change that behaviour. To reverse the direction, just position them apart initially (current + delta) and flip the delta signs so they now move in opposite direction

Comment: There's no limitation - the objects aren't moving in 45% angles, each object's angle and distance is determined solely by `deltaX` and `deltaY`. You can have as many objects as you want, each traveling in whichever direction you want

Comment: Yes, I just did a real world test of this. Its still not 100% effective. The lack of a limit is going to be an obstacle. Yes, I see now how the deltas operate. I will need to try to maybe add some conditionals to stop it, otherwise it may not work in this application. Ideally more of the website (text information, etc.) will be below this, and ideally I would have liked to have another assembly explode further down the screen. Once an assembly is off screen though, it needs to stop. Check out the actual implementation I am thinking about here: http://dev.atomiklan.com/

Comment: Perhaps I can alter the math to only explode the first assembly when scrolling from 0% to 20% and the next assembly from 50% - 70% as an example.

Comment: Any last feedback? Thanks

Comment: If you get stuck post a new question and send me the link, I'll try to answer it

Answer (score 1):

**There is a basic w3school tutorial without jQuery:**

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

---

**Using jQuery:**

http://www.youon.it/parallax-scroll-in-css-jquery-tutorial-delleffetto-in-parallasse/

http://devfloat.net/jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials/

**Edit**

http://stephen.band/jparallax/

Comment: I have looked at all those examples in the past (and again recently). Those are basic parallax examples regarding transitions. I have not been able to apply those examples to image motion in different directions.

Comment: Well that is very very cool. That would be a different way of setting things up, but not exactly what I had in mind. Let me add an update above with some images to explain.