# Convert scrollTop to incremental value

Tags: javascript, math

This is really just a math question but I can't find out how to do it.  I want to use the `scrollTop` to slowly decrease the `opacity` of an object.  So when `scrollTop == 1`, I want `opacity` to be `1`, `scrollTop == 2`, I want `opacity` to be `.99`, `scrollTop == 3`, `opacity` `.98`. Can someone help me with the math to do this?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you need to find the height of the scrollable area, and divide the `scrollTop` value by that value to get the percentage.  I did something similar in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259544/image-motion-when-scrolling-using-jquery/42288000#42288000

Comment: I don't see why I need another variable...I just need to conver 1 to 1, 2 to .99, 3 to .98, etc.  Why do I need another variable to do this.  Can't I do it with pure math?

Comment: I've just answered that kind of uses the same thing! If you like to take a look here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42354638/6647153!

Comment: You are presuming that scrollTop runs from 0 to 100. It can have any maximum. It depends on the amount of scrolling the scrolling window needs to allow for

Comment: Or just post some HTML so we can understand what you want to acheive!

Comment: My calculation in my first comment is wrong - `scrollTop` max is the difference between the content height and its container height. I was typing a bit quickly. The example I linked to uses the correct calculation however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an answer to exactly what you're asking, then you could do the following:

```
var position = window.pageYOffset;
var opacity = Math.max(0, 1 - (position / 100));
```

This, as other commenters have suggested will however result in the opacity reaching 0 after scrolling 100px.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var doc = document.documentElement;

window.onscroll = function() {
var value = window.scrollY / (doc.offsetHeight - doc.clientHeight);
document.getElementById("preview").style.opacity = 1 - value;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#container {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 26%, transparent 75%, #eee 76%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 26%, transparent 75%, #eee 76%);
  background-color: #444;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}

#preview {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```